# openFDA: Is There an Open Database of Which Drugs are Approved for the Treatment of Which Illnesses?

Tags: openfda, medical

Is there an open database which lists FDA or EMA approvals of drugs for the treatment of specific illnesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the question is here.. Yes, openFDA is a database that is free to use, has it's source code on github, and can be queried to find drugs for specific treatments. Part of the api query has a field called "purpose" that should be what you are looking for.

(Github Profile) https://github.com/FDA/openfda
(API guide) https://open.fda.gov/drug/label/

Comment: I think they are asking about a dataset with drug name and purpose. The truth is that this isn't really available in the SPL cleanly-- only as prose aka not in a structured form. If I remember correctly, I was once able to get this info with a combination of sources using rxmix.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the data is available in openFDA to be queried.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Drugs@FDA database: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm.

Comment: As far as I can see that database lists drugs but doesn't list the illnesses for which they are approved.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the NIH RxNorm and related tools to help you link an FDA-registered therapy with its purpose. For instance, ATC classification is a mechanism for classifying the therapeutic purpose of a medicine.

Comment: If you have your own question don't write it in the answer but ask a new question.